# How to set path in linux?

Tags: java, linux, struts2

I have developed a web application using Struts2, java and mysql. When I hosted this application on linux VM server it is not working. I think it is due to some path problems.

This is my Java class:

```
import com.altoopa.utils.DBConnection;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class VideoBuffer {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

            public String readVideo() throws IOException, SQLException {    
                    try {

             int i =0;
             String s=null;
               Date currentDate3 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            System.out.println(currentDate3);
            int _day3 = currentDate3.getDay(); //Getting day
            System.out.println(_day3);
            String current_day3 = null;
            if (_day3 == 0) {
                current_day3 = "Redday";
            } else if (_day3 == 1) {
                current_day3 = "Violetday";
            } else if (_day3 == 2) {
                current_day3 = "Indigoday";
            } else if (_day3 == 3) {
                current_day3 = "Blueday";
            } else if (_day3 == 4) {
                current_day3 = "Greenday";
            } else if (_day3 == 5) {
                current_day3 = "Yellowday";
            } else if (_day3 == 6) {
                current_day3 = "Orangeday";
            }
            System.out.println(current_day3);
            Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            int week3 = cal3.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); //Getting week
            System.out.println(week3);

              DBConnection db=new DBConnection();
              Connection con=db.getDBConnection();
            String  query="SELECT calender_id FROM calender_altoopa WHERE week='" + week3 + "' and altoopa_day='" + current_day3 + "'";
          PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
           ResultSet rs_scrc=ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs_scrc.next()) {

                 i = rs_scrc.getInt(1);
               System.out.println("calender iddfdsfdsfdsfsff"+i);

            }
            String query1="select video_name from sgbg_video where calender_id= ?";
             PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(query1);
             ps1.setInt(1,i);
           ResultSet rs_scrc1=ps1.executeQuery();

            while (rs_scrc1.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs_scrc1.getString(1));
                 s=rs_scrc1.getString(1);
                 System.out.println("videoooooooooooo"+s);`enter code here`

            }
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Dk\\"+"\\"+s));

            String userImageFileName = "temp.mp4";
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "D:\\sreejith_\\altoopa_6\\web\\VideoFile" + "\\"
                            +s));
            int c;
                        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
            while ((c = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("Writing to file...");
                out.write(buffer,0,c);
            }
            out.flush();

            return s;
        }
                catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fis.close();
            out.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using this class I stream the video file from D:Dk folder in writing   it in VideoFile folder inside  NeatBeans application directory.

My question is: What path should I put instead of "D:\Dk\"+"\"+s to deploy the application on to linux VM? I am fetching video from this directory and putting in
        "D:\sreejith_\altoopa_6\web\VideoFile" + "+s));

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>``
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
      <context-param>       
        <param-name>FileUploadPath</param-name>
        <param-value>D:\Dk</param-value>        
    </context-param>
     <context-param>        
        <param-name>AudioUploadPath</param-name>
        <param-value>D:\AltoopaAudio</param-value>      
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Please help me how to put path for deploy this application onto Linux.

Comment: Linux don't have drives like `D:`, and \  is not a special character in file paths (only `/` is, but it is good practice to use only letters, digits, underscores and dots in file paths)  ... it has [mounted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change configuration in `web.xml` but it is not good for multi-OS build (when use maven you need to configure activations and have many web.xml or transform them on build time).

Better way, IMO, is to configure system variables and use them like:

```
System.getenv("UP_FILE_PATH");
System.getenv("UP_VIDEO_PATH");
```

But the best is create configuration table in DB and put it there. More than your configuration class could contain method that get OS type and read proper vars from DB.

Comment: tnx. but i asking for path.cause in linux D,E..Drive.i have use <param-value>D:\Dk</param-value>.so what path i should use instead of this in linux.

Comment: /home/apphome/ is nice practice. Application Server start as apphome user.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at those hardcoded file paths ("D:\...")in your code.  Better take it out to a .properties file or database table, as they surely don't exist in your Linux box

EDIT:

Sorry, I may have not understood your problem.  You should talk to your operator to prepare a location in disk for your videos in the Linux box (maybe /videos, remember Linux and Unix OS have no unit letters).

But that path is not your problem, you should dedicate a minute to think what are your needs.  For example, is your application meant to be in production?  In that case, how much space do you think you will need?  Your operator will surely tell you they need an accurate estimation, because production cabin space for VM boxes is quite expensive.  Think too in that case how will you do to ensure scalability if your needs grow (maybe you need to prepare some kind of NAS?)